# JS: Render value from json into HTML not working

Tags: javascript, json, es6-promise

I would like to print the value "task" of a JSON object into HTML. But I get an Error.
Thanks for any help in advance!

Code:

```
fetch('gamesets\\starter-content\\1.json')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(success => document.getElementById("gamecard-content").innerHTML = success.data[0].task);
```

Error:

```
app.js:143 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at app.js:143:90
```

JSON stored at gamesets\starter-content\1.json (path is correct in my setup)

```
[
    {
        "$schema":"v04cardSchema.schema.json",
        "author":"me",
        "task":"taskText"
    }
]
```

JSON Schema

```
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "author": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "task": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "author",
          "task"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

HTML (excerpt)

```
<p id="gamecard-content"> Waiting for cards to render... </p>
```

Comment: `fetch('gamesets\\starter-content\\1.json')` should be a web resource like a URL with http://. Or a relative path to a local file.

Comment: @ITgoldman it is supposed to be a relative path. I can see that it actually loads the correct file from the network tab in the browser debugger, so I think my mistake must be somewhere else. It might look weird because I escaped the \ but it works

Comment: Maybe the `data => data.json()` makes the data `undefined`.  Try `data.text()` then `console.log`  then `JSON.parse` to see if and where is the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to get data out of success argument but the success argument is actually is your data. And the reason for that is you are parsing a data in the previous then.

Try doing this

```
fetch('gamesets\\starter-content\\1.json')
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(success => document.getElementById("gamecard-content").innerHTML = success[0].task);
```

As you can see, I am accessing first element of an array on the success argument itself.

Hope this helps.